# Rudin's PMA: Theorem 3.29 Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 3.29: If $p>1$,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\log\ n)^p}
$$
converges; if $p\leq1$, the series diverges.

Proof: The monotonicity of the logarithmic function implies that $\{log\ n\}$ increases. Hence $\{1/n\ \log\ n\}$ decreases, and we can apply Theorem 3.27 to the series above; this leads us to the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^k\cdot \frac{1}{2^k(\log\ 2^k)^p}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k\log\ 2)^p}=\frac{1}{(\log\ 2)^p}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^p}
$$
and Theorem 3.29 follows from Theorem 3.28.

I have two questions:
(1) How can we get the decrease of $\{1/n\ \log\ n\}$ from the increase of $\{\log\ n\}$? I didn't see any conncection between them.
(2) The author said that we can apply Theorem 3.27 to the series. However, in order to apply Theorem 3.27, I think we need to show $\{1/n\ (\log\ n)^p\}$ is decreasing. But I don't know how to do that.

Theorem 3.27: Suppose $a_1\geq a_2\geq\cdots\geq0$. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^ka_{2^k}=a_1+2a_2+4a_4+8a_8+\cdots
$$
converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g(x)=x\log^p(x)$ increases and is positive in the interval $(1,\infty)$. From that, it follows that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log^px}$ decreases on $(1,\infty)$.

The convergence of the series can then be analyzed either by the integral test or Cauchy's condensation theorem, as you proposed in your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I think the monotonicity of $g(x)=xlog^p(x)$ also depends on p. For example, $p=-3$, I found that $g(x)$ is not always increasing.

Comment: I just focused on the case $p>0$. For $p<0$ the divergence is easy.

Answer (score 1):

- When $p=0$ divergence is direct for in such case you get the harmonic series $\sum_n\frac1n$.
- For $p<0$ notice that $\frac{\log^{-p}}{n}\geq \log^{-p}2\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq2$ and so, the series diverges in such cases.
- For $p>0$, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3758547/121671), your summand is increasing in which case you can apply Cauchy's condensation test as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Product of two non-negative increasing functions is increasing. Any positive power of an increasing function is increasing. So $n \log n$ and $n \log^{p}n$ are increasing. If $f$ is increasing and $>0$ then $\frac 1 f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know this knowledge before.